# How to collapse rows based on conditions of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `df` like

```
df = data.frame("A" = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
                "B" = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
                "C" = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))
```

I wanted to collapse to only one row if there is at least one "TRUE" per column, like

```
      A     B     C
1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I wonder how we do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
colSums(df) != 0

    A     B     C 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `apply()` can be useful:

```
#Data
df = data.frame("A" = c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"),
                "B" = c("FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"),
                "C" = c("FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"))
#Apply
apply(df,2,function(x) any(x=='TRUE'))
```

Output:

```
    A     B     C 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or setting logical values:

```
#Data 2
df = data.frame("A" = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
                "B" = c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE),
                "C" = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))
#Apply
apply(df,2,function(x) any(x==TRUE))
```

Output:

```
    A     B     C 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), any))
#     A    B     C
#1 TRUE TRUE FALSE
```